# Can computer change his AD Domain Site binding on network reconnection?

Tags: active-directory, domain

Can a computer's AD DS site be reassigned on network reconnection?

For example, I connect a computer to network 172.16.1.x, and then boot it up. The computer recognizes the subnet as belonging to '`Default-First-Site`' and assigns itself to this site.

I then disconnect the computer from the network and connect again to subnet 172.16.2.x. Will the computer change it's site assignment to '`Second-Site(ex.)`'?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you talking about how a client computer identifies the network it's connected to? I'm pretty sure you want to ask questions about DNS, but not AD. Regardless this question seems off-topic, as you don't seem to have a problem to fix.

Comment: @Reaces OP is talking about AD sites and services.  In AD, there is a concept called "Sites" which is used to control replication among AD Domain Controllers (and possibly other things).   See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782048(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: @Edwin is rigth, I am asking about AD Sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the AD bindings are made on reboot but that means that is has been moved from the OU structure. It might be worth it to have a look over here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754697.aspx . The computer will only see the change after the reboot.

Comment: Found information on :doh: [SAMBA wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Active_Directory_Sites#Verify_Domain_Controller_choice_of_a_client) :
_Clients do their Site discovery during startup - not during logons! If e. g. the site membership of a client or the DC(s) in a site change, you have to reboot the client to make the changes effective._